# jQuery or JavaScript nested sortable with top-level restrictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am looking for a jQuery plugin (or pure JavaScript solution) which allows for drag & drop sorting of nested lists. I have come across several examples of this but I need one which will allow particular restrictions.

The restrictions I need are that top-level items can be reordered but cannot be moved to a sub-level. Also sub-level items cannot be moved into top-level positions but can be moved between top-level items as a sub-item.

I hope that makes sense! I've spent ages searching for a plugin to do this but to no avail. There are some good nested sorting options available but none which will do this. Any suggestions appreciated, plugins or how to build this myself.

Thanks!

**Update:**
From my own research the following do not seem to support these kind of restrictions:
jQuery UI sortable, <strike>nestedSortable</strike>, jQuery Sortable, HTML5 sortable, Nestable

**Problem solved:**
Further research into the options available when using nestedSortable suggests that setting protectRoot to true is the solution

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: @BradM This is not shopping. I am not asking for the best answer to my problem from a set of existing answers. I am asking for the help finding the solution to a problem for which I cannot find the answer despite a concerted effort on my own part. There is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved using [nestedSortable](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) and setting protectRoot to true. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq4DM/)...

```
    $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
        protectRoot:true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that Jquery UI should be able to handle this. Their sortable has ways of restricting what can be sorted. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

Comment: Every element needs to be sortable but only into certain positions. jQuery UI sortable seems to be able to prevent an item being sortable altogether only.

Comment: @Michael Henson You can make it so that elements can be sorted into other lists, or not.  So if you link all your inner lists, but don't link those to your top level, I think that will get you the result you wanted. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: I have just realised that nestedSortable should do what I need if I use the protectRoot option. Thanks for the alternative though.

Comment: np, glad you figured it out